# dashes in the url is breaking site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I came across this weird issue. The following url breaks my website by giving 'Forbidden. You don't have permission to access / on this server.' error:
http://www.example.com/q?=11223-222-323dd-3232-dd44

However if I remove one dash
http://www.example.com/q?=11223-222-323dd-3232
It works! Basically four dashes in url breaks the website where three is still OK. What could possibly be causing this??

This is how my .htaccess looks like

```
RewriteEngine on

php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_value docref_root 1
php_value docref_ext 1
php_value error_reporting 1
#php_value error_reporting 1
php_flag  log_errors on
#php_value error_log  /var/logs/php_error_logs/casino_live.log
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

php_value register_globals          0
php_value session.auto_start        0
php_value session.cookie_lifetime       604800
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime        604800
php_value session.cache_expire      200000

php_value session.use_only_cookies 1
php_value session.use_trans_sid 0

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^PHPSESSID=.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301]



AddType text/x-component .htc
RewriteRule ^robots.txt robots.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1  !/example.com/(.*)$
RewriteCond $1  !^/index.php/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1  ^/example.com/(.*)$
RewriteCond $1  !^/example.com/index.php/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /example.com/index.php/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com|example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^lobby/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/lobby/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Do you have any rewrite rules in your configuration? If so, show them.

Comment: Nobody can guess your code or setup. Sounds like a typical mod_security issue though.

Comment: Sorry, added my .htaccess

Comment: If you are using a framework then some will typically rewrite URLs with dashes in to be Camel cased behind the scenes. For example: Zend Framework has URL's like `www.blahblah.com/my-function` this then gets translated to look for a function called `myFunction`. In your example you say it works when you remove the last set of dashes, which coincidently have `-dd44`

Comment: sorry please swap q with ?. Nah I still get the same error

Comment: Replace the `-dd44` at the end with `-5644` does this work or break?

Comment: turns out this was a server thing - protection against sql injections.